# Dell PowerEdge bios update failure. Error finding file: update.xml

Tags: dell-poweredge, update, upgrade, bios

So I downlaoded the latest BIOS for a Dell PowerEdge server. Attempting to update using the EXE fails. The error from the GUI states to restart the server. Restarted but still failed.

I found the log file and see that it states:

```
<< PACKAGE LOG >>Y entered; update was forced by user
<< PACKAGE LOG >>Executing update...
<< PACKAGE LOG >>Device does not impact TPM measurements.
FQDD Parameters are : 

Error finding file:  update.xml

<< PACKAGE LOG >>The update failed to complete; you must restart your system and try again.
<< PACKAGE LOG >>==============================> Update Result <==========================
Update was not applied
```

I am running the upgrade as Administrator. I have tried a couple different exe for this hardware from the Dell website with no luck. I have also tried to disable virtualization technology from the BIOS as a dell article stated.  Any thoughts on what is going on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LCC was disabled. Enabled and the update proceeding without issues.